# A WP-ADMIN directory appeard on my public_html

Tags: title, google-search, wp-admin

Today, a strange folder appeard in my public_html directory.It's named wp-admin and has a file in it named n184976 with a lot of lines of code.

Since this, the title of the website changed,so when i search on google my website it will appear,but the title will be something in japannese.

Plus that, the index file was replaced by another index.php with a strange include(i deleted that).

I need to specify that i didn't used wordpress or something like this.

It's my website hacked?
If i delete this strange directory the title will come to normal?

Comment: You should ask your hosting service. Who are you using?

Comment: I'm using cpanel

Comment: Unless it was someone else on your team, I would reach out to CPanel. Maybe they install wordpress from default. Maybe there is some issues with their shared hosting.